# CSS Animations using just Opacity and Transform

Tags: css

I read an interesting article the other day and I've been trying to apply it in my workflow.

https://blog.gyrosco.pe/smooth-css-animations-7d8ffc2c1d29#.5a2q978fv

One of the concepts that are mentioned is the idea of only animating elements with opacity and transform. I've been implementing this idea over the last few days and find it pretty awesome.

One issue I've come across is if an element is at opacity 0 the containing parent will still apply the space of the child element. I tried to remove the space with scaling the child element to almost nothing but the space is still persistent.

I was curious if anyone has worked in this manner and has advice on how to animate a parent element to grow with the child element?

```js
function showHiddenBox() {
  let hiddenBox = document.querySelector('.hiddenbox')

hiddenBox.setAttribute('data-state', hiddenBox.getAttribute('data-state') === 'hidden' ? 'visible' : 'hidden');
}
```

```css
.parentbox {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #564d49;
}
.showingbox {
  display: flex;
  align-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #63cdff;
}
.hiddenbox {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  transition: all 1s;
  background-color: pink;
}
.hiddenbox[data-state="hidden"] {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scaleY(.1) translateY(-50px);
  transform-origin: top;
}
.hiddenbox[data-state="visible"] {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentbox">
  <div class="showingbox">
    <button onclick="showHiddenBox()">Click Me</button>
  </div>
  <div class="hiddenbox" data-state="hidden"></div>
</div>
```

To further explain myself I've created this snippet. I want to create an animation with just opacity and transform where the brown of the parent element doesn't show but the parent will expand when the child is created.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function showHiddenBox() {
  let hiddenBox = document.querySelector('.hiddenbox')

hiddenBox.setAttribute('data-state', hiddenBox.getAttribute('data-state') === 'hidden' ? 'visible' : 'hidden');
}
```

```css
.parentbox {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #564d49;
}
.showingbox {
  display: flex;
  align-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #63cdff;
}
.hiddenbox {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  transition: all 1s;
  background-color: pink;
}
.hiddenbox[data-state="hidden"] {
  max-height: 0;
  transform: scaleY(.1) translateY(-50px);
  transform-origin: top;
}
.hiddenbox[data-state="visible"] {
  max-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentbox">
  <div class="showingbox">
    <button onclick="showHiddenBox()">Click Me</button>
  </div>
  <div class="hiddenbox" data-state="hidden"></div>
</div>
```

Use max-height instead of opacity. Over exaggerate the max-height. Depends on how it will work for you. Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes, that will work. I was curious if it was possible with just opacity and transform. But I don't have to be a purest ;P To be honest I don't see any possible way of doing with the two styles. I just figured I'd put the question out there and see if anyone had a better idea.

Comment: You cant. Since opacity is just adjusting the transparency of an element and its child. If you want to have better performace. Use GreenSock Tweenmax. It is easy to use. :) :D